# Custom JavaScript button URL redirect

Tags: apex, javascript

I've setup a JavaScript button on a custom object *Prospect__*c that creates a new Contact record and updates the current *Prospect__c* record.
Everything works as expected except the redirect URL right at the end. It ends up in "*myorg*.salesforce.com/Undefined" with a URL no longer exists message on the page. I also have a lookup field that will link to the newly created Contact record, which is also empty at the moment, as I'm not able to get the Id back and use it - either in the URL or the Lookup field. 
Any ideas? Thanks

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/36.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/36.0/apex.js")}
var Prospect__c = new sforce.SObject("Prospect__c"); 
   Prospect__c.ID = '{!Prospect__c.Id}';   
   Prospect__c.converted__c = 'True';
   dt= new Date();
   dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+0);
   Prospect__c.converted_date__c = dt;
var result = sforce.connection.update([Prospect__c]);


var newRecord = [];
{
   var Con1 = new sforce.SObject("Contact");

   Con1.OwnerId = '{!Prospect__c.OwnerId}';
   Con1.LastName = '{!Prospect__c.contact_name__c}';
   Con1.Locale__c = '{!Prospect__c.locale__c}';
   Con1.Email = '{!Prospect__c.email__c}';
   Con1.Phone = '{!Prospect__c.phone__c}';
   Con1.Description = '{!Prospect__c.description__c}';
   Con1.Billing_Zip_Code__c = '{!Prospect__c.Billing_Zip_Code__c}';
   Con1.Billing_Street__c = '{!Prospect__c.Billing_Street__c}';
   Con1.Billing_Country__c = '{!Prospect__c.Billing_Country__c}';
   Con1.Billing_City__c = '{!Prospect__c.Billing_City__c}';

   newRecord.push(Con1);
}
var result2 = sforce.connection.create(newRecord);
console.log(result2[0]);
if (result[0].success == 'false') {
    alert(result[0].errors.message);
} else {
   window.parent.location = "/" + result2.Id;
}
```

In case you're interested, I also tried this approach

Answer (score 1):

You have a very minor mistake in your code. It is result2[0].**id** not result2.**Id**

```
var result2 = sforce.connection.create(newRecord);
console.log(result2[0]);
if (result[0].success == 'false') {
    alert(result[0].errors.message);
} else {
   window.parent.location = "/" + result2[0].id;
}
```